# AWS Lambda (in python) waiting for asynchronous event

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, aws-lambda

I've got an AWS Lambda, written in python and behind API Gateway, which makes a network request out to a third party.

Shortly after that request, a separate request will be made by the third party to the URL of my choosing - I need to get a hold of the body of that request and return it in the response from my Lambda.

If perhaps I have the third party send to a second Lambda, how can I hold the first Lambda open, waiting for an event from the second Lambda?

Comment: Another option might be to immediately return a correlator to the client and expose a 2nd API route that the client can call later with the correlator to request the result of the first operation.

Comment: I'd (vastly) prefer something that doesn't involve polling, but that would work.

Comment: i have the same question, actually im looking in "aws step functions"

Answer (score 0):

(In the hope that someone offers a better idea...)

What I'm currently intending to do is stand up a redis (Elasticache) cluster. Lambda A will send out a request with an X-Request-ID and then setup a redis pubsub().subscribe(X-Request-ID). Lambda B will receive the response and do a redis pubsub().publish(X-Request-ID, response). Lambda A will then return the response or, if not received in time, timeout.

Inelegant but I think it works.